# Firebase Permission denied when reading data after authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase. I authenticated the user using email and password -

```
final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithPassword("app@firebaseio.com", "password", new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
        System.out.println("User ID: " + authData.getUid());
        getData(ref);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

But after authentication when I am reading the data, I am getting `Permission Denied`.

```
private void getData(Query ref) {
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

These are the Firebase rules.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firebase's permission model only allows the user access to data that you explicitly give access to. Since in your security rules, you only give access to `/users/$uid`, the user cannot read from root `/`. The Firebase documentation covers this under ["rules cascade"](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade).

You seem to want to use security rules to filter data, which is not possible with Firebase's security model. See the section ["rules are not filters"](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter) in the Firebase documentation as well as these previous questions and answers:

- [firebase security permission not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732705/firebase-security-permission-not-working)
- [firebase rules not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139215/firebase-rules-not-working)
- [How to use Firebase rules to only give permission to certain leaf nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038981/how-to-use-firebase-rules-to-only-give-permissio)

The simplest solution is to allow read of the `users` node:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'"
        }
    }
}
```

And then query on that level:

```
getData(ref.child("users"));
```

Comment: Good point on the rules cascade, thank you for sharing more info for the rules. I would also like to mention another fix using [identical firebase sdks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657873/firebase-permission-denied-after-auth), this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got this exception using a slightly different approach to read from my database, but this is how I solved the issue.

First of all, my database rules looked liked this:

```
{
"rules": {
  "student": {
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Earlier on, to write to to the student database, I used this code in my Activity:

```
 mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
    ...
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setPhoneNumber("+23480547455343");
    student.setCountryOfOrigin("Nigeria");
    mDatabaseReference.child("student").child(user.getUid()).setValue(student).
                addOnCompleteListener(DetailsCaptureActivity.this, 
                                   new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
     ...
     });
```

Notice how the child name (student) matches the child name in the firebase data rules?

Now to read the data of this user, I did this:

```
 //Set up an AuthStateListener that responds to changes in the user's sign-in state:
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {

                   databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("student").child(user.getUid());
                   databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                          Student student = dataSnapshot.getValue(Student.class);
                          phoneNumberTextView.setText(student.getPhoneNumber());
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                          Log.e(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
                      }
                  });

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };
```

I got the permission denied exception if I did only:

```
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(user.getUid());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Firebase has a bug, that after authentication, you have to wait until user appears in the `FirebaseAuth`, and then you can use it.

What I did is waited for it to appear, like

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> signInImpl())
        .map(this::toFirebaseUser)
        .map(this::waitForUserToAppearInAuthenticator)
        .flatMap(this::doSomethingInDatabase);
```

Where

```
@NonNull
private FirebaseUser waitForUserToAppearInAuthenticator(@NonNull final FirebaseUser user) {
    final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener l = firebaseAuth -> {
        final FirebaseUser cu = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (cu != null && user.getUid().equals(cu.getUid())) {
            cdl.countDown();
        }
    };
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(l);
    try {
        cdl.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(l);
    }

    return user;
}
```